# Event triggered when changing a user Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

### Detect events from a user Firebase Authentication

In my application developed in **Angular** along with **Node.js** and **Firebase** I need to detect events occurring in users. As inclusion, change and exclusion.

Is there a way to detect when a user is deleted, changed, or inserted through a function created in [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/?hl=en)?

I know that you can detect database events with a function created in Cloud Functions. I would like to detect when a user is changed, deleted or entered when the operation is done through **Firebase Console > Project > Authentication**.

**Something in that sense:**

```
exports.userChanged = functions.user
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {})

OnDelete()
OnCreate()
OnChange()
```

### What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I am not clear what you're asking. Can you reduce the scope of the question? E.g. if you want to know if it is possible to trigger a Cloud Function when a user's profile is updated, limit your question to that. The answer to that would be that it's not possible btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933827/firebase-auth-onupdate-cloud-function-for-when-a-user-updates-their-email

Comment: narrowed the scope of the question. What I need to do is detect events when a user is inserted / changed or deleted.

the same way that happens when I create a function using Cloud Functions to detect events from the Realtime Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `onCreate` and `onDelete`, you can read it from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events).

For the update case, you should rely on the RTD. Actually, you could rely completely on the RTD.

```
//Create a user on the rtd
functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    return usersRef.child(user.uid).set(user);
});

//Update the user by listening to a change on the RTD
functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
         //If you needed it you can update the user
         admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
         });

         //if some condition, then delete it
         admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)

         //do more
    });
```

Using the update user option you can even disable the account, take a look at this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481932/4017501)

You can use the admin sdk inside of Functions directly, this is the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users)